# Google Translate API proxy

Tags: google-translate

Im investigating the translate API and the example script contains a warning advising me to use a proxy to hide my api key.

```
// WARNING: be aware that YOUR-API-KEY inside html is viewable by all your users.
// Restrict your key to designated domains or use a proxy to hide your key
// to avoid misuse by other parties.
```

I am just wondering how do I run the script via a proxy?

UPDATE: Thanks for this.. I have since removed the project as it was made redundant.  But great advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in this instance the reference to proxy means a server side encapsulation (or something similar) to hide the API key. You'd therefore make a call to your server, which would proxy the call to Google instead of making the call in client-side Javascript and exposing your API key.